# Date String causing error in NSMutableURLRequest URL using swift language

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am passing date after converting to String but causing error

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping a value
```

this is code of Request

```
let url = SERVICE_URL + "GetHistoryDataByTerminalNo?TerminalNo=\(VehicleList.SelectedTerminal.selectedTerminalId)&fromDate=\(fromDateText)&toDate=\(endDateText)"
    
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL,
                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                       timeoutInterval: 30.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
```

**UPDATE**
I am getting this URL

http://labs2.unitedtracker.com/api/Trackers/GetHistoryDataByTerminalNo?TerminalNo=351535058776063&fromDate=2020-08-23 14:15:52.000&toDate=2020-08-23 16:15:52.000

Comment: Your url seems to be invalid. Can you put a breakpoint on the second line of your snippet and report back what `url` is?

Comment: @Alladinian Let me share in Update

Comment: Use URLRequest and URL instead of NS... types

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just put a string with a space into a URL, you have to URL-encode it first.

First of all, add `extension` for URL encoding:

```
extension String {
    public var urlEncoded: String {
        var allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowedCharacters.remove(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]")

        return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Second, encode the parameter values:

```
let url = SERVICE_URL + "GetHistoryDataByTerminalNo?TerminalNo=\(VehicleList.SelectedTerminal.selectedTerminalId.urlEncoded)&fromDate=\(fromDateText.urlEncoded)&toDate=\(endDateText.urlEncoded)"
```

Or, you could use [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) and [URLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlqueryitem) to generate your URL.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not messing around with URL encoding manually - we have `URLComponents` for this.

For example:

```
let SERVICE_URL = "https://example.com/service/"
let url = SERVICE_URL + "GetHistoryDataByTerminalNo"
var components = URLComponents(string: url)!

components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "TerminalNo", value: VehicleList.SelectedTerminal.selectedTerminalId),
    URLQueryItem(name: "fromDate", value: fromDateText),
    URLQueryItem(name: "toDate", value: toDateText)
]

let request = URLRequest(url: components.url!, timeoutInterval: 30)
```

(you probably want a little more error checking)

Also, as @Joakim mentioned, don't use NS... types if you can avoid them.

Comment: I still prefer to encode manually. `URLComponents` can't encode the `+` character properly. In most cases it will work though.